# cannot costomize specific url only for url-loader in webpack 2

Tags: jekyll, font-awesome, github-pages, webpack-2

TL;DR, The `font-awesome css` cannot be show on my blog correctly, because I cannot only make a url for font-awesome css, and [my blog online address](https://dxcqcv.github.io/)  and [github address](https://github.com/dxcqcv/dxcqcv.github.io).

I create a blog on github page, used pug to convert html, stylus to convert CSS, and little ts, and webpack + gulp to build, everything is OK, but awesome css url is wrong, I use `webpack-2` and `gulp-4`.

The config about awesome css in webpack is

```
...
  output: {
    path: PATHS.bin,
     //publicPath: '{{site.baseurl}}',
   // use / to show awesome css icon
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: debug ? 'js/[name].js' : 'js/[name]-[hash:8].js'
  },
...

...
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.woff(\?v=\d+\.\d+\.\d+)?$/,
        use:[{ loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit:'10000',
            mimetype:'application/font-woff',
            //name:'fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash:8]'
            name:'fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash:8]'
          }
        } ]
      }, {

...
```

The blog file struct is

```
.
├── about
│   └── index.md
├── _config.yml
├── credits
│   └── index.md
├── css
│   ├── commons.css
│   ├── commons.css.map
│   ├── index.css
│   ├── index.css.map
│   ├── pages.css
│   └── pages.css.map
├── favicon.ico
├── fonts
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.eot
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.svg
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.ttf
│   ├── fontawesome-webfont.woff
│   └── fontawesome-webfont.woff2
├── Gemfile
├── Gemfile.lock
├── gulpfile.js
├── images
│   └── shangwenlong-wechat.png
├── _includes
│   ├── articles.html
│   ├── disqus.html
│   ├── pagination.html
│   └── sidebar.html
├── index.html
├── Jenkinsfile
├── js
│   ├── commons.js
│   ├── commons.js.map
│   ├── index.js
│   ├── index.js.map
│   ├── pages.js
│   └── pages.js.map
├── jsconfig.json
├── _layouts
│   ├── default.html
│   ├── page.html
│   └── post.html
├── LICENSE
├── media
├── node_modules
├── package.json
├── _posts
│   ├── 2016-07-07-webpack-for-jekyll.md
│   ├── 2016-08-13-gemfile-requires-error.md
│   ├── 2016-10-07-mongoose-arrowFunction-bug.md
│   ├── 2016-12-03-gulp-watch-problem.md
│   ├── 2016-12-04-pug-loader-problem.md
│   ├── 2016-12-05-github-pages-problem.md
│   ├── 2016-12-24-min-height-does-not-work-in-qq-browser.md
│   └── 2017-03-01-reactjs-improvements.md
├── README.md
├── _site
│   ├── about
│   ├── blog
│   ├── credits
│   ├── css
│   ├── favicon.ico
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── Gemfile
│   ├── Gemfile.lock
│   ├── images
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── Jenkinsfile
│   ├── js
│   ├── jsconfig.json
│   ├── LICENSE
│   ├── page2
│   ├── README.md
│   ├── src
│   ├── static
│   ├── test
│   ├── tsconfig.json
│   └── webpack.config.js
├── src
│   ├── css
│   ├── fonts
│   ├── _includes
│   ├── index.pug
│   ├── js
│   └── _layouts
├── static
│   └── highlight
├── struct.txt
├── test
│   └── index.html
├── tsconfig.json
└── webpack.config.js
```

the awesome css need a url in css is `../fonts/xxxx`, but it's `/fonts/xxx`, so make it cannot display correctly.

you can see if I change `publicPath` only for awesome css to use `../`, then the other `js` and `css` will be linked wrong, but I cannot make a url only for `awesome css` and do not change other sources. help~, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

just set publicPath in `ExtractTextPlugin`, it can override global output `ExtractTextPlugin`

```
  /********* stylus to css*/
  {
    test: /\.(styl|css)$/,
    exclude: ['/node_modules/','/src/css/includes/'],
    use:ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      publicPath: '../',
      use:['css-loader','postcss-loader','stylus-loader']
    })  
  },
```